# Git Merge conflict with renamed or deleted file

Tags: git

Branch B was created from Branch A; 
In Branch B
File.cs was renamed to FileName.cs, additional changes commit and pushed on that file. 
In Branch A
Changes were committed to File.cs in Branch A.

Pull request on branch B to branch A is having merge conflicts. 
How to resolve this conflict?

Comment: Did merge and commit from branch B into branch A; After this pull request automatically got resolved..

Comment: "Created from" is not really relevant (since branch labels move).  What matters during a merge is the *merge base*, which is determined from the commit graph, and the diffs between (1) the base and your current commit and (2) the base and your merge target commit.  You can see these diffs with `git diff`.  Usually if someone's pull request does not merge cleanly, that means they (the request-er) needs to rebase their code so that you have a different merge base.

Answer (score 0):

It's nearly impossible to answer this because there could be anything causing the conflict from a white space to the file rename itself.

Just curious though, If you were to tell git which one to choose, which one would you expect to be chosen? Do you want your changes to Branch A to be File.cs + your changes in FileName.cs (from B)? Or do you want Branch A to be FileName.Cs + both changes in the files from each branch? See the conflict?

I would suggest you open them both in a text editor/code compare tool and manually merge what you need to merge.

If renaming files like this is a common problem for you, you should A) Converse with your team to understand why files are being renamed all the time or B) Write a script to handle these things. See this article for more information: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging